# Why aren't my collection view cells showing...?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

It's been a while since I programmatically created a collection view and I can't seem to find why my cells are not showing. Delegate and Datasource are being set. Size is being set and it is not too big.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCV()
    }

    var containerCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cv
    }()
}

extension ViewController {
    fileprivate func setupCV() {
        // these first two lines add the colelction view and apply constraints - they work and the CV is properly displayed inside the view controller
        self.view.addSubview(containerCollectionView)
        containerCollectionView.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

        containerCollectionView.delegate = self
        containerCollectionView.dataSource = self

        containerCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want your layout to be an instance of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` not `UICollectionViewLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing the wrong layout.

try this:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```